# Strange GDB behavior in OSX

Tags: malware, gdb, osx, x86, mach-o

I'm reversing some malware on an OSX VM when I noticed something peculiar. While stepping through the instructions, the instruction just after a `int 0x80` gets skipped *i.e.* gets executed without me stepping through this.

**Example:**

```
 int 0x80
 inc eax ; <--- this gets skipped
 inc ecx ; <--- stepping resumes here
```

Why does this happen? Have you encountered something similar to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When single-stepping through code, the `T` flag is set so that the CPU can break after the instruction completes execution.  When an interrupt occurs, the state of the `T` flag is placed on the stack, and used when the `iret` instruction is executed by the handler.  However, the `iret` instruction is one of a few instructions that causes a one-instruction delay in the triggering of the `T` flag, due to legacy issues relating to the initialization of the stack.

So the skipped instruction is executing but you can't step into it (but if you set a breakpoint at that location and run to that point instead, then you will get a break).

Comment: +1. Didn't sound like the OP was interested in those low-level details, but now I understand why you were arguing that my answer didn't contain the information asked for. But it turns out I misread the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Do we observe the same behavior in other OSes ? *BSD, Linux, OpenSolaris, ... ?

Comment: @perror: should for all practical purposes whenever an interrupt handler is used and therefore `iret` is used.